# Getting SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error. in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I am facing the `SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.` while running the `drawImage()` function.

In my project i have 5 set of image slides. So very first slide throws an error, second slide works fine and from third slide on-wards its showing `SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error.`

Its showing the error in `ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,parseInt(startSize[0]),parseInt(startSize[1]));` this line.

I have specified the sample code below

```
 if(source){

        img.src = 'data/program_images/'+source;
        position += speed;
        var drawTimeLen = endTime - startTime;
        if(Math.round(videoTime) == startTime){
            polypoints.length = 0;
            position = 0;
        }
        if (position > polypoints.length - 1) return;
        var pt = polypoints[position];
        rotation += rotationSpeed;
        // draw
        clearCanvas();
        ctx.translate(pt.x, pt.y);
        ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,parseInt(startSize[0]),parseInt(startSize[1]));
        ctx.restore();
    }
```

I put this code in a function and that function is called up in looping. Its working in Chrome/Firefox but not in IE.

Please anyone give me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Give the image time to load before trying to draw it. You can give the image time to load by using `img.onload` and doing the `drawImage` inside .onload. Also be sure that the 2 startSize parameters are valid.

Comment: Thanks for giving idea. I used you img.onload, Its not showing any error. but some of the sliders are skipped. I don't want to skip/leave any slider

Comment: If some images are skipped, you probably should preload all the slider images before starting the slider.  Here's one script that loads all the images and then calls a callback function.  You can start your slider inside the callback knowing that all images are available.  https://github.com/epistemex/YAIL2-images-loader-for-JavaScript

Comment: Link from markE is dead.